# Declare constructors of class with a constant array (or arrays) as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm a new at C++ and heared of such powerful technic - templates.

Here are my constructors inside the my class

```
    node(const double f) {
        this->type = FLOAT;
        this->data.f = f;
    }
    node(const int i) {
        this->type = INTEGER;
        this->data.i = i;
    }
    //construct a vector
    node(const vector<int> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
        }
    } 
    node(const vector<double> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
        }
    }
```

it helps me to do this kind of things

```
node* obj_i = new node({{1, 0},{0, -1}});
node* obj_f = new node({{1.0, 0.0},{0.0, -1.0}});
```

I did have to write down the initializers twice for the integer and float types of arrays. Is there any way to do it using templates and replace the last two functions with one?

Thanks

**UPD**
I went deeper and declared the constructor of matrixes and got error

```
    //construct a matrix    
    node(const vector<vector<int>> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
        }
    } 
    node(const vector<vector<double>> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
        }
    }
```

```
error: call of overloaded 'node(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
     node* matrix2 = new node({{0.0,7.7}, {3.3,-9.2}});
```

I seems to be that my technic fundamentally wrong...

Comment: [`std::variant<int, double>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you have to declare a template.

```
template<typename T>
node(const vector<T> arr) {
    this->type = LIST;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
        this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

Also, you have to make changes in your code accordingly

```
node* obj_i = new node<int>({{1, 0},{0, -1}});
node* obj_f = new node<double>({{1.0, 0.0},{0.0, -1.0}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest solution is to declare a template for any vector:

```
template<typename vector_t>
node(const vector<vector_t> &arr) {
    this->type = LIST;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
        this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

And yes, there is a very good reason for using a reference -- this avoids making a completely useless, and pointless, copy of whatever vector gets passed in as a parameter.

The only downside is that this will also participate in overload resolution for, say, `std::vector<char *>`. This will likely to end in tears, and an avalance of confusing error messages. It will be preferrable to have this participate in overload resolution only for `int` and `double`, resulting in a more palatable "hey, there's no such constructor" error message. This will require a little bit more work, and will be a different question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers (sorry, i don't have enough points to vote). But I did have to modify suggested solutions.
This works perfectly for me

```
    //construct integers, floats
    node(const double f) {
        this->type = FLOAT;
        this->data.f = f;
    }
    node(const int i) {
        this->type = INTEGER;
        this->data.i = i;
    }
    //construct a vector
    template<typename T>
    node(initializer_list<T> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr.begin()[i]));
        }
    }
    //construct a matrix
    template<typename T>
    node(initializer_list<initializer_list<T>> arr) {
        this->type = LIST;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) {
            this->data.args.push_back(new node(arr.begin()[i]));
        }
    }
```

The usage

```
    node* matrix1 = new node({{1,3},{2,3}});
    node* matrix2 = new node({{2,7},{4,5}});
```